# Why is my SimpleMap widget not accessing my _countrycode variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I'm trying to use the country code variable that I declared and stat updated into my Text Field but somehow when I try using it in my Simple map Widget it says that the named parameter isn't defined. Can someone explaine me what I'm doing wrong please? Not sur how to fix that problem...

here is the code :

```
class WorldMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorldMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<WorldMap> createState() => _WorldMapState();
}

class _WorldMapState extends State<WorldMap> {
  late String _countryName;
  late String _countryCode;
  List<Map<String, String>> countries = [
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "aF"},
    {"name": "land Islands", "code": "aX"},
    {"name": "Albania", "code": "aL"},
    {"name": "Algeria", "code": "dZ"},
    {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "aS"},
];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: "Enter the name of a country",
              ),
              onSubmitted: (String userInput) {
                setState(() {
                  _countryName = userInput;
                });
                for (var element in countries) {
                  if (element["name"] == _countryName) {
                    setState(() {
                      _countryCode = element["code"]!;
                    });
                    print(_countryCode);
//change color instead of print
                  }
                }
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 35),
            SimpleMap(
              // String of instructions to draw the map.
              instructions: SMapWorld.instructions,

              // Default color for all countries.
              defaultColor: Colors.grey,

              // Matching class to specify custom colors for each area.
              colors: const SMapWorldColors(
                //_countryCode: Colors.green, // This line don't work why?
                uS: Colors.green,
                bE: Colors.red,
              ).toMap(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `SimpleMap` for your case

Comment: It's a widget comming from this dependecie : https://pub.dev/packages/countries_world_map

Answer (score 0):

remove `const`, because the `_countryCode` isnot const.

```dart
 colors: SMapWorldColors(
```

For color, try to create a map variable on state class.

```dart
  Map colors = SMapWorldColors(
    uS: Colors.green,
    bE: Colors.red,
  ).toMap();
```

And onSubmitted

```dart
onSubmitted: (String userInput) {
  setState(() {
    _countryName = userInput;
  });
  for (var element in countries) {
    if (element["name"] == _countryName) {
      setState(() {
        _countryCode = element["code"]!;
        colors[_countryCode] = Colors.green;
      });
      print(_countryCode);
//change color instead of print
    }
  }
},
```

And use on SimpleMap like

```dart
 colors: colors,
```

Comment: I tried removing the const it still says that the named parameter "_countryCode" isn't defined

Comment: ok, the issue is it is using constructor named arguments

Comment: Okay, not sur what that means or how to fix the issue :p

Comment: Thanks! I don't have the same error but the color doesn't change on the map! I'll try figuring that out now :)